# onclick recyclerview fragment kotlin

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Following Code works perfectly on Activity but not on fragment

```
class MyProjects(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    init {
        view.setOnClickListener { println("Test") }
    }

    var partyname = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtBorn)
    var service = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtFirst)
    var status = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtLast)

    fun bind(b: String, f: String, l: String) {
        partyname.text = b.toString()
        service.text = f.toString()
        if (l == "completed") {
            status.text = "C"
            status.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"))
        } else {
            status.text = l.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Kotlin…

Comment: Can you brief about the errors you're getting?

Comment: How are you setting it up in your fragment?